Pandas DataFrame/Seaborn Heatmap - Sorting the x-axis
Alright I have this Dataframe named histo_df:
       date/time opened              Label    month year

0   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup  June 23   23
1   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup  June 23   23
2   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup  June 23   23
3   2023-06-27 10:03:00       Batch Import  June 23   23
4   2023-06-27 10:00:00       Core Adapter  June 23   23
..                  ...                ...      ...  ...
275 2024-05-15 08:36:00               HPTC   May 24   24
276 2024-05-15 12:04:00            Unknown   May 24   24
277 2024-05-16 01:23:00              HADES   May 24   24
278 2024-05-17 11:38:00             Brands   May 24   24
279 2024-05-17 12:27:00    Forgot Password   May 24   24

I created a heatmap of it,everything looks great except the x-axis is out of order

This question is different from other questions Ive looked at because the x-axis should be ordered by Month/Year since the dates attached to each label start mid year and flow into the next year, and can be different according to the csv file I import.
Original code:
#Create a new DataFrame for the histogram data
histo_df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_path, usecols = ['Label','date/time opened'], on_bad_lines='skip')

#Convert to datetime
histo_df['date/time opened'] = pd.to_datetime(histo_df['date/time opened'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')

#Add a month and year column
histo_df['month'] = histo_df['date/time opened'].dt.strftime('%B') #Ive tried ('%B %y') here too
histo_df['year'] = histo_df['date/time opened'].dt.strftime('%y')

#Make a pivot table and heatmap
df = histo_df.pivot_table(index='Label',columns='month', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
sns.heatmap(df, cmap="YlGnBu", annot=True, fmt="0.0f")
plt.show()

Various things I've tried at different times taken from various other posts:
histo_df.groupby(["year", "month"], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({'Label':'sum'}) 

#histo_df = histo_df.sort_values('month') 

#histo_df = histo_df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1) 

#df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1) 

#df = df.sort_index(level=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)

I promise, I tried the things above from many other posts that I've been looking at.

I added that in there, and it did order the X-Axis to be Jan, Feb, March etc. but there are 2 problems now:

All of the counts are zeroed out:

date/time opened              Label month year
0   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup   NaN   23
1   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup   NaN   23
2   2023-06-27 10:03:00  Environment Setup   NaN   23

Probably related to #1 but these dates start midyear and go into the next year (and can be different according to each csv I import so hardcoding = bad) so it should be June 23, July 23,...Jan 24, Feb 24 etc.


See How to create a categorical column of month names with incomplete months. Suppose you used dt.strftime('%B %y'), then  cat = histo_df['month'].unique() and histo_df['month'] = pd.Categorical(histo_df['month'],ordered=True,categories=cat).

That was it. Thank you very much. I dont know how long it would have taken me to get to that. I guess I havent used df.unique() and pd.cateogrical that much before now! Thank you!
